# Display the content of a module in Front-end Preview

Tags: contao

I am integrating a module in Contao CMS version 3.4.5. The module is working fine in the backend. The module is about discussions and forums and the users can create discussions and other users can answer on it. I have set up the front-end module for the module. I wanted to display the discussion forums in the front-end. But it's not working.

Comment: Can you please describe it a little bit more, what is not working and what did you exactly do to display it?

Comment: I solved the problem. There was error with the template file which was creating the error and the front-end preview was not loaded.